# how to solve MPV issue - X11 error: GLXBadFBConfig

Tags: xorg, opengl

I'm having an issue with MPV (the MPlayer2 fork). I set it to use the OpenGL Video Output because it looks/performs the best on my laptop (older Intel). However, every time I open a video, it gives me an error stating "X11 error: GLXBadFBConfig" and proceeds to tell me "Could not create GLX context!" but still displays the video, which makes me think it's using a fallback video output (probably the X11 vo).

I've looked it up and it seems it's caused by the video driver not supporting the level of OpenGL the application is trying to use, but I used the OpenGL VO on MPlayer2 without issue.

Is this a known issue? Is there any way to fix it?
I'm using Manjaro (Arch-based) x86_64 Testing branch, so I've got the latest Mesa and drivers...

Comment: This site is dedicated to programming issues, if you had a problem with some code you wrote we could help you. But as it stands, this would be more appropriate on another Stack Exchange network such as Super User.

Comment: Sorry, I got Stack Exchange and this site mixed up :(

Comment: Well, technically Stack Exchange is the parent of this site. It started out as just this site, but then expanded into multiple sites that work the same way for different topics. Super User is the particular specialized site on the Stack Exchange network that deals with user issues. It can be confusing, but this keeps the Q&A focused so that "Related" is not cluttered up with completely irrelevant topics.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you have an older Intel laptop. It looks to me that it just may not support VA-API. Only G45 and later systems support it. Look at the `vainfo` output. You may try the option `--hwdec-codecs=all` to see whether other codecs work.
You can also have a look at [this Github issue](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/885), which sheds some light on a similar problem in greater detail. Basically, the issue shows the terminal output of playing a file, which would reveal information:

```
mpv --vo=opengl --hwdec=vaapi:

Playing: test.avi
File tags:
encoder: MEncoder git-ab94fc6-4.4.3
title: test.avi
[stream] Video (+) --vid=1 (mpeg4)
[stream] Audio (+) --aid=1 (mp3)
[vo/opengl/x11] X11 error: GLXBadFBConfig
[vo/opengl] Could not create GL3 context. Retrying with legacy context.
Using software decoding.
```

Comment: Providing a link to more information is discouraged on SuperUser. Instead you should copy/paste the relevant data and embed it in your post. If that link ever becomes invalid, your answer will loose its value.